# Why does Phenylalanine to Tyrosine release H2O?

Tags: biochemistry, aromatic-compounds, enzymes

So I was reviewing Tyrosine and Phenylalanine metabolism (according to [this video](https://youtu.be/sOUVczoOCIo)) and maybe I'm missing something but in the first step, 1:

[image]

Oxygen atom reacts with Phenylalanine to make up Tyrosine, but the remaining Oxygen atom reacts with what exactly to end up as H2O?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The remaining oxygen reacts with the cofactor (called tetrahydro biopterin) of the enzyme phenylalanine oxidase, which loses two hydrogens to become dihydro biopterin (the oxidized form of the co-factor):

[image: Gerald Litwack Ph.D., in Human Biochemistry, 2018]

As for why: this is a monooxygenase, and an alternative would be to have $\ce{H2O2}$ as a product, but that's a reactive oxygen species the cell is better off without.